# Read and loading depends on file extension

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way that will automatically open the href link rather than downloading it. For example the file extension is xlsx it will open excel or jpg, png will do image viewer.

Temporarily here is what I got. I created a function on my controller then my view will do the download using the attribute element:

**Controller:**

```
 public IActionResult DownLoad(string param)
  {
      var file = param;
      string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
      webRootPath = "//MyRootpath";      
      var addrUrl = webRootPath + "/" + file;

      var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(addrUrl);
      return File(stream, "application/force-download", file);
}
```

**View**

```
<a class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true" href="/File/Download?param=test.xlsx>zTest.xlsx</a>
```

Any suggestion/comments. TIA

Comment: For Excel, try passing "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" for the contentType parameter. It won't guarantee it'll be opened but there's a better chance. The Content-Type header tells the UA what file type it is. File extensions don't matter. There's no "one size fits all" for this. You have to set the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: Also, use "application/octet-stream" to force download, not "application/force-download".